# In Node, Why does trying to re-declare the iterator of a JavaScript for-loop give a "not defined" error instead of a "duplicate declaration" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code prints a "duplicate declaration" error in Node.

```
let i = 2;
let i = i;
// Duplicate declaration "i"
```

However, inside of a for-loop, a different curious error happens when accessing 'i'. I expect there to be a duplicate declaration error. Instead, I get 'i is not defined'.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let i = i;
} 
// ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

Why would i be not defined? Why a ReferenceError instead of Duplicate declaration?

Comment: Using `var` in the for loop makes `i` bound not only to the loop scope, but also to the scope the loop is in (like if it is in a function, for example). So I think the error is because when you declare a new variable with `let`, if it has been declared in an outer scope it's ignored in the current scope, since it has the same name, so `i` is not defined in this scope yet.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'i' before initialization` with node `12.16.2`

Comment: @Phiter I have edited my question to change var to let to eliminate that as a factor. The same error occurs whether you use let or var in the iterator declaration.

Comment: @EricGuan I'm actually using v10.16.0. Maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first situation, the error occurs during `let i`, since i has already been declared in the same scope.

```js
let i = 2;
let i = i;
//  ↑ i is already defined in current scope
```

---

In for loops, there're actually two scopes. In the nested scope, you can redefine `i`, it will simply obscure the outer scope `i`.

But the error occurs when accessing the value of `i`, because you're accessing it while defining it since the inner `i` hasn't been initialized.

```js
let i = 0;
{
  let i = i;
  //      ↑ i hasn't been initialized yet, you can't access it as a value
}
```

Comment: v8 doesn't support that syntax, even though `let j = i` would work.

Comment: @Matt It supports, but don't try it here in StackOverflow's console since `i` has already been declared by them for some reason lol

Comment: @HaoWu i mean doesn't support `let whatever = whatever`

Comment: @Matt I think it can only produce an error despite the engine, not just V8. The compile phase is ok but the error occurs at runtime.

Comment: @HaoWu ok, js doesn't support it then but it's not a leap for a language to access the outer scope variable of the same name but someone decided no. it's a not a good idea anyway =)